# html two input values get swapped

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to send a http request to a website and I need the user to fill out their names and mobile number. I'm trying to do it as followed (I'm still working on the validate function so right now it always return false. )

```
<html> <meta charset="UTF-8" />

<script type="text/javascript">

    function validate(){
        var a = document.forms["sendform"]["mobile"].value;
        alert(a);

        return false;
    }

</script>

/*<style>

.myButton {
    background-color:#4a45c7;
    -moz-border-radius:28px;
    -webkit-border-radius:28px;
    border-radius:28px;
    border:1px solid #193eab;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:17px;
    padding:16px 31px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #282b66;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 45%;
}

.userNameField{
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    left: 45%;
}

.userEmailField{
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left: 45%;
}

.userMobileField{
    position: absolute;
    top: 35%;
    left: 45%;
}

.userName{
    position: absolute;
    top: 32.5%;
    left: 38%;
}

.userEmail{
    position: absolute;
    top: 37.5%;
    left: 38%;
}

.userMobile{
    position: absolute;
    top: 42.5%;
    left: 38%;
}*/

</style>

    <body>
        <?php

        $stcate = $_POST["stCate"];
        $stcode = $_POST["stCode"];
        $result = $stcate . $stcode;
        ?><br> 
            <form name="sendform" id = "sendform" method="post" action="https://www.ezship.com.tw/emap/ezship_request_order_api.jsp" onsubmit="return validate();">


            <p class = "userName"> 取件人姓名 </p>
            <input type="text" name="rv_name" id = "name" class = "userNameField"/> <br>

            <p class = "userMobile"> 取件人電話</p>
            <input type="text" name="rv_mobile" id = "mobile" class = "userMobileField"/> <br>


            <input type="hidden" name="st_code" value= "<?php echo $result;?>"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="rv_addr" value="" />
            <input type="hidden" name="rv_zip" value="" />
            <input type="hidden" name="rtn_url" value='http://localhost/orderstatus.php' />
            <input type="hidden" name="web_para" value='yes' />

            <input type="submit" class = "myButton" value='確認寄出' />

        </form>


    </body>
</html>
```

After I entered some values for both inputs and hit send, the alert always prints out the value for input "name" even though I'm trying to print out input "mobile". The same thing happens when I try to print out value for "name", it just prints out value for "name". I don't understand why the values are swapped? I tried it without any PHP code and CSS and it works the way I expect. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Consider removing the ```<style>``` part from your code above, as it doesn't have influence on the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have a `head` tag. That may be the problem with it's running correctly without style tags and php code. Try adding the `head` tag.

Answer (score 2):

Since the attribute `mobile` that you're using is an `id`, so you can use `document.getElementById("sendform").value` like this:

```
function validate(){
    var a = document.getElementById("sendform").value;
    alert(a);
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the `name` attribute of the input as the index of the array, so instead of `var a = document.forms["sendform"]["mobile"].value` it should be `var a = document.forms["sendform"]["rv_mobile"].value`.

Comment: I tried that but it still prints out the wrong value :(

Comment: @ChungYang If you want to debug it and find out the issue, try logging some vales. For example, in the `validate` function try `console.log(document.forms['sendform'])` and see what that object contains (you can see the log in the Javascript console of your browser). Maybe it will help you see what's missing or what you have in the form object.